# UITableViewController.UIView.trailingAnchor has different position than UIViewController.UIView.trailingAnchor

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, nslayoutconstraint

I have a method to add two circles to the background view. When added to the view of a `UIViewController`, they get added correctly. However, when added to the view of a `UITableViewController`, they get added to the other side.

The method to create the circles is:

```
extension UIViewController {
    func makeCircle(radius: CGFloat) -> UIView {
         let circle = UIView()
         circle.backgroundColor = .yellow
         circle.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
         circle.layer.cornerRadius = radius
         NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
             circle.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: radius * 2),
             circle.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: radius * 2)])
         return circle
    }
}
```

The method to add the circles within the `UIViewController` extension is:

```
func addCircles() {
    // Center right circle
    let circle1Radius = CGFloat(152)
    let circle1 = makeCircle(radius: circle1Radius)
    view.addSubview(circle1)
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        circle1.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor),
        circle1.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: circle1Radius)])

    // Bottom left circle
    let circle2Radius = CGFloat(77)
    let circle2 = makeCircle(radius: circle2Radius)
    view.addSubview(circle2)

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        circle2.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: 70),
        circle2.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: -50)])
}
```

For both classes, the circles get added inside the `viewDidLoad` method:

```
 class ViewController: UIViewController {
      override func viewDidLoad() {
          super.viewDidLoad()
          addCircles()
      }
 }
```

The `ViewController: UIViewController`, the view looks correct:

[image]

However, for the `TableViewController: UITableViewController` (exact same `viewDidLoad` as for controller above), the output looks opposite:

[image]

Can someone give me a tip on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Thanks. The use of opacity was inside `makeCircle`, `circle.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow.withAlphaComponent(opacity)`. I just copied-pasted the code above and can still reproduce in a new project.

Comment: Ok, so the problem is that in the table view controller, your constraints are ambiguous. To see this, run the app and switch to the View Debugger.

Comment: I saw that, but could not figure out why they are ambiguous in the tableController, but not in the simple `UIViewController`.

Comment: I assume it's because a table view is a scroll view. Remember, constraints from a scroll view's subview to a scroll view have a completely different meaning from constraints from a normal view's subview to its superview. So adding subviews directly to a table view using constraints is going to work oddly.

Comment: Thanks! I did not know that constraints to scroll views would behave that differently. It makes sense. Would you mind posting that comment as an answer so I can mark it? I no longer use a `UITableViewController`, but a normal `UIViewController`, add the circles and and then add a `UITableView` to the `UIViewController.tableView`.

Comment: I learnt today what "ambiguous layouts" are and did not think it was so relevant. Sorry for wasting your time.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @matt's comment:

> I assume it's because a table view is a scroll view. Remember, constraints from a scroll view's subview to a scroll view have a completely different meaning from constraints from a normal view's subview to its superview. So adding subviews directly to a table view using constraints is going to work oddly.

What solved my issue was to no longer use a `UITableViewController`, but a "basic" `UIViewController` that has a `UITableView` and implements the `UITableViewDataSource` and the `UITableViewDelegate`:

```
class TableViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        addCircles()
    }
}
```

Comment: But do note that now the circles will not scroll with the table view, as your original example did. As long as that's okay, this is a good solution. If you do _not_ want the circle views to scroll, then another solution, in modern iOS, would be to pin the circle views to the table view's `frameLayoutGuide` instead of the table view itself.